# Changing font size of a button

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, datatemplate

In my .xaml file these are my resources:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:KeyModel}">
    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="26" Margin="0" >
        <Run Text="{Binding Content.Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

And here's the style:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="#006AB6" BorderThickness="1" Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid" >
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
</Style>
```

And in code I have:

```
<Button Name="btn_Q" FontSize="8" Content="{Binding KB.Key_Q}" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource RoundCorner}"/>
<Button Name="btn_A" Content="{Binding KB.Key_A}" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource RoundCorner}"/>
```

But the FontSize for btn_Q doesn't get to be 8. How can I fix it? I need to make only btn_Q to have a fontsize of 8. All of my other buttons, like btn_A are fine with the style's fontsize.

Comment: Is this WPF or Windows RT or Windows Phone 8?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware It's WPF.

Comment: Works fine for me.  http://i.imgur.com/7qTMjIi.png

Comment: I agree with @ChubosaurusSoftware... there is no problem with your displayed XAML. If you want help, you need to provide a working code example that demonstrates your problem... your current code does not do that.